# why do we need to create an auxiliary array to rearrange it?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

i'm new to c++ and working through the problem of rearranging a sorted array in O(n) time so that first comes the maximum element, then the minimum, then the second max, then the second min, so it goes.

my solution doesn't pass the tests without an auxiliary array result to which I then copy over my values - see below for the initial and the working solutions:

```
// initial:
void maxMin(int arr[], int size) {
  bool switchPointer = true;
  int min_ptr = 0;
  int max_ptr = size - 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (switchPointer) {
      arr[i] = arr[max_ptr];
      max_ptr--;
    } else {
      arr[i] = arr[min_ptr];
      min_ptr++;
    }
    switchPointer = !switchPointer;
  }
}

// working
void maxMin(int arr[], int size) {
  int* result = new int[size];
  bool switchPointer = true;
  int min_ptr = 0;
  int max_ptr = size - 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (switchPointer) {
      result[i] = arr[max_ptr];
      max_ptr--;
    } else {
      result[i] = arr[min_ptr];
      min_ptr++;
    }
    switchPointer = !switchPointer;
  }

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        arr[j] = result[j];    // copying to original array
    }
  delete [] result;
}
```

why do we need an auxiliary result array? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because if you apply your algorithm "in-place" you will overwrite MIN values of your original array before you could use them. Imagine:

```
arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

expected result is `{5, 1, 4, 2, 3}`

- in first iteration you will do `arr[0] = arr[4]  // arr[0] is equal to 5 now`
- in second iteration you will do `arr[1] = arr[0]  // but this is not what you want, because arr[0] was already changed and is not equal to "1" anymore`

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use temp variables when you need to read your original source of data and not the modified version. In your case I think the problem arises when you do
`arr[i] = arr[max_ptr];` or `arr[i] = arr[min_ptr];` in your non working example. In this case you modify the array and you read (`arr[max_ptr]`) the same overwritten array leading to inconsistencies in your algorithm. Using an auxiliary variable solves the issue since you read the original data but you store it somewhere else.